# How can myoglobin be responsible for the red color of meat if it is located in the cytoplasm?

Tags: cell-biology, muscles, pigmentation

How can myoglobin be responsible for the red color of meat if it is located in the cytoplasm, as the visible part of muscle cells is the membrane (at least as I believe)?

Sources:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myoglobin
http://jeb.biologists.org/content/207/20/3441

Comment: Presumably for the same reason that red cells are, well, red.

Comment: — I am not a moderator. As a retired educator I believe that students learn better if they are asked to think about their questions. The additional examples I provided should suggest to you that cell membranes are effectively transparent — think about any other pigmented cell. So your question becomes one of the optical physics of biological membranes. I suggest you phrase it in those terms and submit it to a more appropriate list.

Comment: +David I don't see any example you've provided, maybe due to a server error. Secondly, I didn't know that cell membranes were transparent; in any case it would have been better if you had answered normally and not only by letting a comment. Thanks!

Comment: I am not a physicist, which is why I phrased the comment the way I did. I presume cell membranes must be transparent from examples such as haemoglobin but I cannot answer the question why, which presumably lies in the realm of biophysical optics.